# How to prevent 'conda env export' from updating specific dependencies

Tags: python, pip, conda, dependency-management

Here's an excerpt from my `environment.yml`:

```
name: my-project
channels:
  - pytorch-nightly
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pytorch=1.13.0.*
  - pip:
    - https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/nb_core_news_md-3.3.0/nb_core_news_md-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
prefix: ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/my-project
```

When I create my environment (`conda env create -f environment.yml`) and re-export it to `environment.yml` (`conda env export > environment.yml`), the file gets changed:

```
name: my-project
channels:
  - pytorch-nightly
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pytorch=1.13.0.dev20220614=py3.9_0
  - pip:
    - nb-core-news-md==3.3.0
prefix: ~/opt/miniconda3/envs/my-project
```

Then, when I re-create my environment the next day, Conda complains that `pytorch=1.13.0.dev20220614=py3.9_0` does not exist because it was replaced by a new PyTorch Preview (Nightly) build. `dev20220614=py3.9_0` is no longer available.

Conda also complains that `nb-core-news-md==3.3.0` does not exist. It was installed via a URL directly to the `whl`. That URL was removed from the `environment.yml`.

How can I prevent `conda env export` from changing these two dependencies? I still want Conda to lock down the specifics for all other dependencies, just not for these two.

Comment: Try using the `--no-build` flag when exporting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69011426/14536215

Comment: Ah! The `--no-builds` flag worked well for `pytorch` (yay!) but not for `nb-core-news-md`. For the latter package, the URL was still removed.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: It did not work for `pytorch` either, actually, because `dev20220614` is apparently part of the _package_ version and not the _build_ version. For `pytorch`, only `=py3.9_0` was removed when using the `--no-builds` flag. My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I think PyTorch is not following the build versioning conventions that work with Conda. I have opened an issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/79606

Answer (score 0):

I get why PyTorch is deleting daily builds, but it's kind of disruptive for the workflow you have. What you're asking for cannot be expressed with Conda CLI commands. Instead, consider exporting the regular YAML, but then run some `sed` commands to replace the particular requirements prior to recreating the environment.